# Spinor norm of the pth power of a matrix

Tags: normed-spaces, finite-fields, classical-groups

Let $F_{q}$ be a finite field of order $q=p^{r}$ ($p$ odd) and let $V$ be a $3$-dimensional vector space over $F_{q}$. Consider the subgroup $\Omega(3,q)$ of $SO(3,q)$., where we are picking the standard basis $e,f,d$ which satisfies $(e,e)=(f,f)=(e,d)=(f,d)=0$ and $(e,f)=(d,d)=1$.

I would like to show that for any element $A\in \Omega(3,q)$
$$sp(A)=sp(A^{p}),$$
where $sp$ denotes the spinor norm and $A^{P}$ denotes raising each entry of $A$ to the $p$-th power.

I have tried to write $A$ as a product of reflections but I am not sure how to write $A^{p}$ as a product of reflections using that so that I can then deduce the spinor norm of $A^{p}$. Any help with this method, or another method would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I think I may have found an argument. The map which raises each entry of a matrix to the $p$-th power is a map from $O_{3}(q)\to O_{3}(q)$ and so induces a map from the derived subgroup of $O_{3}(q)$ to itself, i.e. $\Omega_{3}(q)\to \Omega_{3}(q)$. I still need to convince myself of the last assertion though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but since the spinor norm is a morphism of groups
$$
\mathrm{sp}\colon \mathrm{SO}(3,q)\rightarrow \mathbf F_q^\star/\mathbf F_q^{\star2}
$$
one has
$$
\mathrm{sp}(A^p)=\mathrm{sp}(A)^p=\mathrm{sp}(A)
$$
in $\mathbf F_q^\star/\mathbf F_q^{\star2}$, since $p$ is odd.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to define what I meant by $A^{p}$ - I meant raising each entry of the matrix $A$ to the $p$-th power. I've just edited my original post to reflect this.